# Whats the amount of money in 你明天带着两万两前去天琴城，买我赢得第一?

Tags: translation

你明天带着两万两前去天琴城，买我赢得第一。

Google says 220,000 taels, but I’m not really sure. Could someone clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

两 = 二 = 2

万 = ten thousand

两 = tael

两万两 / 二万两 = 20,000 taels (of silver)

One tael is about one ounce.

20,000 ounce of siver is about $400,000 US dollars

> *Google says 220,000 taels*

I got "Two thousand two" from Google. There's something wrong with Google Translate about this phrase (we all know Google Translate is not always reliable)

Comment: 二万二 should be 22,000 right?

Answer (score 2):

it means 20000 两, the first 两 means 2, the second 两 is a unit.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on context here. 两万两 could be either ***20000 taels*** or ***22000(块)***. You should look into more context to determine here.

P.S. From my experience, some people would say 两万两 to mean 22000, especially older people or people whose dialects have the preference. E.g. in Shanghai, 两 is used more than 二. I wouldn't be surprised when they say 两千两 to mean 2200.

Comment: If it was 22000(块) , we would use 二万二   or 两万二 instead of  两万两

Comment: @TangHo Well, some people did say 两万两 for 22000, although I don't prefer that way.

Answer (score 0):

Google translation is wrong. It should be 20,000两, where 两 is a unit. However, I'm not sure about the actual metal used here. It can be Silver of Gold, but it's likely to be Silver. I would say we need more info about the context. We are sure that it's not 220,000 (actually even if the machine interpreted it as 二万二, it should be 22,000 instead. Maybe something wrong with Google's algo)